# tables exceeding page margin in tcpdf

Tags: php, html, margin, tcpdf

I'm generating a pdf file using tcpdf , the pdf is contains some long descriptions that the user has already inserted in a textarea (using tinymce). Some users have descriptions with width tables (mostly they just copy/paste from word files to the textarea) , when the pdf is generated these tables exceed the margin and only a part is visible.
i tried to put it in a div , a table , div inside table, word-break , white-space ,table-layout, display: table ... , fixe the margins in tcpdf... :

```
$pdf->SetMargins(10, 30, 5);
```

the latest thing i tried is :

```
$html = '<style>
    .dd table{
        word-break:break-all;
        white-space:pre-wrap;
        width:650px;
        table-layout:fixed;
        display: table;
        color:red;
    }

</style>

<div id="dd" class="dd" style="background-color:#ffffff;"> <br />'.decoder($ligne['description']).'</div> <br /> <br />
';
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
```

i can change the font color of the tables to red so i know the style is applying, but not the part about not letting it exceed the margin.
I'm thinking it's because tcpdf is suporting limited css attributes.
I thought about using writecell instead of writeHTML but their is too much variable text (can be 5 lines or 10 page) , i can't know wheir is starts or where is stops.

Any ideas on how to fit the tables inside the div or table so it won't exceed the margins and doesn't get cut off.

Thank you.

Comment: From the code posted I would assume the css won't apply as there is no table inside your div. Have you tried applying the overflow controls to the td instead?

Comment: the table is in here $ligne['description']. the overflow control would either hide it , clip it or put scrolls, and i want neither , i want it to break line.

Answer (score 0):

I am very late to the party, but my guess is that tinymce is (or was) adding `width` to either the table or the `td` elements. Parsing the HTML and removing the offending attribute should solve the problem.

It could also be that those css rules are not applied by TCPDF, or that the target should be the `td` elements.